# Cycle through list and call function based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items as such:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="Viewer1">click</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Viewer2">click</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Viewer3">click</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Viewer4">click</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Viewer5">click</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are various functions attached to each ID:

```
$j('#Viewer1').click(viewer1);
function viewer1() {
some code...
return false;
}
$j('#Viewer2').click(viewer2);
some code...
return false;
}
$j('#Viewer3').click(viewer3);
function viewer3() {
some code...
return false;
}
$j('#Viewer4').click(viewer4);
function viewer4() {
some code...
return false;
}
$j('#Viewer5').click(viewer5);
function viewer5() {
some code...
return false;
}
```

What I'd like to do is use jQuery to loop over each id and call the appropriate function for a specific interval.

First, Viewer1() is called for say 4 seconds and then Viewer2() and so on ---looping back to Viewer1() and starting over.  I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `setInterval`:

```
var interval, lastCalled = $j('#Viewer1').parent().siblings().last().find('a');

function doStuff () {

    var next = lastCalled.parent().next().find('a');
    if (!next.length) {
        next = lastCalled.parent().siblings().eq(0).find('a');
    }
    //console.log(lastCalled,next);
    next.click();
    lastCalled = next;

}

interval = setInterval(doStuff,4000);
doStuff();
```

Edit: This isn't exactly doing it by Id I guess, it's doing it by the element's location. Changing it to ID wouldn't be too tough if that was a serious requirement.